# How can I know if a particular browser is going to be compatible for a particular syntax?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

As an example, this is an exercept out of the [MDN browser compatability documentation for HTMLElement.offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth#Browser_compatibility):

[image]

It doesn't really tell me if `offsetWidth` is going to work, does it? How can I find this out, without manually testing every version of every browser?

Comment: check this caniuse.com

Comment: Well, by manually testing on every browser. By the time, you'll learn all the gotchas. When you've learned to handle first 200 - 300, you can call yourself "pro".

Comment: If you want to programmatically make sure, if that is available in the browser or in the version that you are using.

if (window.offsetWidth) {
 // it is available
}

In general for addEventListener
if (window.addEventListener) {
// Supports addEventListener
}
if (window.attachEvent) {
// Supports attachEvent
}